# If I have two nodes defined at the end points of a diagonal of a rectangle, how can I define nodes for the other two corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have two nodes which I want to define to be opposite corners of a rectangle.  I would like to be able to define nodes at the other pair of opposite corners.

I tried the following, but it gives me errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

%% ATTEMPT 1
%% ERROR: doesn't match its definition
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (C) at (5,3) {3};
  \node (B) at ($ (A) ! (C) ! ($ (A) + (1,0) $) $) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

%% ATTEMPT 2
%% ERROR: doesn't match its definition
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (C) at (5,3) {3};
  \node (tB) at ($ (A) + (1,0) $ ) {tB};
  \node (B) at ($ (A) ! (C) ! (tB)$) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Why isn't my projection working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use the perpendicular coordinate system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (C) at (5,3) {3};
  \node (B) at (A.center|-C.center) {2};
  \node (D) at (A.center-|C.center) {4};
\draw[red] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- (D.center) -- (A.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`(<name1>|-<name2>)` has the x-coordinate of `<name1>` and the y-coordinate of `<name2>`.

`(<name1>-|<name2>)` has the x-coordinate of `<name2>` and the y-coordinate of `<name1>`.

Comment: This is extremely useful.  Where in the manual can I find this documentation?  In other words, what topic is this discussed under?

Comment: @A.Ellett Section "Coordinate system perpendicular", pages 130-131 of the PGF manual.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the `calc` library doesn't like some of the spaces in the coordinate calculation, when I remove them both your examples work, e.g.

```
\node (B) at ($(A)!(C)!($(A)+(1,0)$)$) {2};
\node (D) at ($(A)!(C)!($(A)+(0,1)$)$) {4};
```

More specifically, as noted by Gonzalo, it is the spaces in `! (<node name>) !` that causes the error, so

```
\node (B) at ( $ (A) !(C)! ( $ (A)+(1,0) $ ) $ ) {B};
\node (D) at ( $ (A) !(C)! ( $ (A)+(0,1) $ ) $ ) {D};
```

will also work.

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {1};
  \node (C) at (5,3) {3};
  \node (B) at ($(A)!(C)!($(A)+(1,0)$)$) {2};
  \node (D) at ($(A)!(C)!($(A)+(0,1)$)$) {4};
  \draw [red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code above]